# Azure Service Fabric On-Premise docker network default ip range

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric

We are running windows containers on an on-premise Azure Service Fabric installation. We are building the fabric nodes from a corporate template (Windows 2016 with container support) that also contains an internal firewall product (also controlling the flows between internal networks in the node). The configuration of this firewall is centrally managed.

In order to correctly configure the firewalls, we need to control the IP range of the docker network. To do this we created or own docker network (of type 'nat') and named it 'xyz'. (as the current docker-ee for windows version does not accept the "fixed-cidr" parameter in the configuration file).

When using containers in service fabric we ran into problems because when the container is started by sf, it tries to attach to a default network named 'nat'. Apparently it is not possible to name a custom network 'nat', or to pass the name of a network to which the container should attach to service fabric (either through classic application package or docker compose file).

To solve the problems following would work:

1. Fix the IP segment address during Docker for Windows installation
2. Have the option to specify the name of the network the container should connect to when started by service fabric (when starting the container manually this can be done with the --network option)
3. ????

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you can do today is option 1.

We are working on 2 :-)

Comment: Sorry if this is not useful, but it's the current product truth.There are no other options today.